# Using VB.Net code to create a barcode in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am attempting to design a barcode to implement into my report. I am using this guide to do this [Code 128 Barcode in SSRS](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29371.code-128-barcode-in-ssrs-open-source.aspx) . I have little experience in VB.Net, I'm receiving an error in my custom code on line 7 that says **Name 'objGraphic' is not declared**. I'm also open to other alternatives to implementing a barcode in my report preferably free.

```
Function PaintBox(ByVal level As String) As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim objBitmap As System.Drawing.Bitmap

objBitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(3,3)

GenCode128.Code128Rendering.MakeBarcodeImage(level, 1, True)

objGraphic.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Gray,0,0,width,height)

Return objBitmap End Function

Function PaintBoxBmp(ByVal level As String) As Byte()

Dim bmpImage As System.Drawing.Bitmap

bmpImage = PaintBox(level)

Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream

Dim bitmapBytes As Byte() bmpImage.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

bitmapBytes = stream.ToArray

stream.Close()

bmpImage.Dispose()

Return bitmapBytes

End Function
```

Comment: The error pretty much says it all -- you didn't declare a variable named `objGraphic`.  Personally, this seems like too much work.  Have you considered adding a [barcode font](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1aada9df-9c2c-44b6-bd00-b3c60b8d1931/barcode-fonts?forum=sqlreportingservices) instead?

Comment: @Steve-o169 Wow, I didn't even come across this through hours of google. Will try this.

Comment: @Steve-o169 all this did was display the barcode in the font but it doesn't actually work.

Comment: Could be the font you're using?  My company uses a barcode font and it works just fine for our purposes.  What doesn't work about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Function PaintBox(ByVal level As String) As System.Drawing.Bitmap 

Dim objBitmap As System.Drawing.Bitmap 

objBitmap = GenCode128.Code128Rendering.MakeBarcodeImage(level, 1, True)

 Return objBitmap 

End Function 

Function PaintBoxBmp(ByVal level As String) As Byte() 

Dim bmpImage As System.Drawing.Bitmap

 bmpImage = PaintBox(level)

 Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream 
Dim bitmapBytes As Byte() 
bmpImage.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)

 bitmapBytes = stream.ToArray 
stream.Close()
 bmpImage.Dispose() 
Return bitmapBytes 

End Function
```